# How to dynamically integrate multiple angular2 subapps into one parent angular2 app

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template

I am working on a use case where I need to place multiple ng2 apps in on main parent app. I can manage the routing using systemjs bundles configuration and 'loadChildren' property in angular2 Routes, but the subapps can have separate paths and separate systemjs config. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You could lazy load multiple @NgModules, where each module is a separate app.

```
compRef: ComponentRef<any>; 
constructor(private moduleLoader: SystemJsNgModuleLoader) { }

this.moduleLoader.load(`/path/to/my/app`)
  .then((moduleFactory: NgModuleFactory<any>) => {
    const vcRef = this.vcRef;
    const ngModuleRef = moduleFactory.create(vcRef.parentInjector);
    const comp = ngModuleRef.injector.get(LazyLoadConfig).component;
    const compFactory = ngModuleRef.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(comp);
    this.compRef = vcRef.createComponent(compFactory, 0, ngModuleRef.injector);
  });
```

Have a look at [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/85zrrDdJoStf0mz7QIHT) for a working example.